# react-native-community_datetimepicker : compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, datetimepicker

It seems to be a compatibility issue. Kottlin & Java

But I don't know how to solve it.

React native cli version is 0.73.0

```
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
```

I did "npm run android".
The error message is as follows.

> todolist@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

> Task :@react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/kwonheejung/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/kwonheejung/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39249073bb6a3501d7fccc77a4a99ba2/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/kwonheejung/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39249073bb6a3501d7fccc77a4a99ba2/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker:androidJdkImage'. > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/kwonheejung/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar. > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/kwonheejung/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39249073bb6a3501d7fccc77a4a99ba2/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/kwonheejung/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39249073bb6a3501d7fccc77a4a99ba2/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules} * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 2s.
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/11#issuecomment-574929166

or
 
https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/pull/13

or

rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npx jetify -r
npm run android:build

I hope the solution I've suggested will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this problem will gone after downgrate `React Native` version to 0.72.x